# Cómo crear un reporte de Excel con NPOI (C#, Framework 2.0)

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio-2010

Estoy haciendo una aplicación de *Windows Forms* en **Visual Studio 2010** con un **framework** muy bajo (**2.0**).  Ésta aplicación debe *generar un reporte* (**Excel**) con datos extraídos de una base de datos.

Probé varias librerías pero requerían *framework* a partir de 4.0, entonces opte por usar **NPOI**. El detalle es que no se cuál versión puede aceptar sin problemas con el framework requerido ya que a partir de la version *2.0 de NPOI* proporciona mas espacios de nombres.

Alguien me podría explicar qué debo usar para crear un reporte de excel con **NPOI**.

Comment: Cuando dice `Reporte` se refiere a crear un `XLS` `XLSX`?

Comment: @J.Rodríguez de preferencia un XLS, aunque por el tipo de framework no se si solo se puedan crear XLSX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este sitio web es un gran recurso para cualquiera que comience con `POI` o `NPOI`.

Es una descripción general rápida de las funciones básicas de la documentación de `POI`, como leer un rango con nombre, colapsar filas, etc. Como `NPOI` es una coincidencia cercana con `POI`, la guía es bastante efectiva.

[Guía de desarrolladores ocupados de funciones HSSF y XSSF](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#NewWorkbook)

Crear un nuevo archivo `.xlsx` usando `NPOI` y escribir en él, aquí está el código:

```
public static void TransferXLToTable()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("City", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("State", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("Zip", typeof(string));

    using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(OpenFile(), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        IWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(stream);
        ISheet sheet = wb.GetSheet("Sheet1");
        string holder;
        int i = 0;
        do
        {
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            IRow row = sheet.GetRow(i);
            try
            {
                holder = row.GetCell(0, MissingCellPolicy.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK).ToString();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                break;
            }

            string city = holder.Substring(0, holder.IndexOf(','));
            string state = holder.Substring(holder.IndexOf(',') + 2, 2);
            string zip = holder.Substring(holder.IndexOf(',') + 5, 5);
            dr[0] = city;
            dr[1] = state;
            dr[2] = zip;
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            i++;
        } while (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(holder));
    }
```

> Fuente SO: [Trying to create a new .xlsx file using NPOI and write to it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19842993/8933039)

---

Otro Ejemplo:

**Edite el archivo de Excel existente con C# NPOI:**

La solución más sencilla y sencilla: abrir el archivo para leer, crear `HSSFWorkbook`, hacer lo que desee en ese libro de trabajo, y luego abrir el archivo nuevamente para escribir en él.

Es seguro usar `hssfwb` fuera del alcance `using` porque `HSSFWorkbook` no contiene referencia al archivo desde el que se leyó (siempre que lo vea en fuentes `NPOI`).

Entonces el código podría verse así:

```
HSSFWorkbook hssfwb;
using (FileStream file = new FileStream(@"c:\temp\testfile.xls", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    hssfwb = new HSSFWorkbook(file);
    file.Close();
}

ISheet sheet = hssfwb.GetSheetAt(0);
IRow row = sheet.GetRow(0);

sheet.CreateRow(row.LastCellNum);
ICell cell = row.CreateCell(row.LastCellNum);
cell.SetCellValue("test");

for (int i = 0; i < row.LastCellNum; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(row.GetCell(i));
}

using (FileStream file = new FileStream(@"c:\temp\testfile.xls", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write))
{
    hssfwb.Write(file);
    file.Close();
}
```

> Fuente SO: [Edit existing Excel file C# npoi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27528945/8933039)

---

**Ademas de otros enlaces que pueden ser de interés:**

> - [How to read in XLSX data for editing with NPOI](http://www.zachhunter.com/2010/05/read-xlsx-data-for-npoi/)
> - [Creating Excel spreadsheets .XLS and .XLSX in C#](https://www.leniel.net/2009/07/creating-excel-spreadsheets-xls-xlsx-c.html)
> - [Create Excel (.XLS and .XLSX) file from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2603625/8933039)
> - [NPOI with Excel Table and dynamic Chart](https://www.leniel.net/2009/10/npoi-with-excel-table-and-dynamic-chart.html)
> - [NPOI 2.0](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=npoi)

Espero te sirva, Saludos!.

Comment: muchas gracias @J. Rodríguez los ejemplos me sirvieron mucho, al principio me confundía pero en los enlances que adjuntaste me sirvieron de ayuda.

Comment: @BrandCodes me alegra que haya servido de ayuda, Saludos!